# Show and hide individual SubSites in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, spnavigationnode

I have created 5 subsites using structured navigation. How can I show only 2 subsites and hide other sites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under `Site Seettings >> Navigation` in the section `Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting` there's a button called "Hide". Highlight the site you want to hide from navigation and click this button.

[image]